# Prevent undefined side effect for new attributes

Tags: javascript

I have an object like these

object.js

```
export default [
    {
      id: 1,
      slug: 'oracle-mysql',
      rules: [],
      // has_children: true, // my developer didnt defined this attributes
      // parent_id: 2, // my developer didnt defined this attributes
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      slug: 'hm-gitu',
      rules: ['ada'],
      has_children: true,
      // parent_id: 2, // my developer didnt defined this attributes
    }
    {
      id: 3,
      slug: 'hire',
      rules: ['scodeid'],
      // has_children: true, // my developer didnt defined this attributes
      parent_id: 2, // have
    }
```

by the way this object has a lot of data, I don't know if there is any defined so I try hard to consume data like these

in here (side-effect) I just set for new attributes for `this.form` without spread operator.

```
const { rules } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id - 1) // some data static has inject before object.id = 2 , so this.form.id - 1 = 2 ( first data i get rules: ['ada'], } 
try {
   const { has_children, parent_id } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id)

    if(parent_id === 2 || parent_id !== undefined) {
     // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
     this.form.parent_id = parent_id
     if (has_children) this.form.has_children = true
    }

    this.form.parent_id = parent_id
    this.form.rules = rules

} catch (e) {
   this.form.rules = rules
}
```

I just want to know how to not use code like these

```
const { rules } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id - 1)
try {
   const { has_children, parent_id } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id)
```

I just want use like these

```
   const { rules, has_children, parent_id } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id)
```

instead of

```
const data = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id)
if(data.has_children) this.form.has_children = data.has_children
```

any option for set all default if undefined or null or empty [] ?
I only know to set default value if empty/null `const { rules = [],`  then how for **set attributes undefined**

If I know the data its look like on above maybe I'm just going on refactor it but I think it's more efficient about the data, but the code need to re-set for undefined attributes.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, but there is the nullish coalescing operator, `??` which will return the left-hand side if it's not null or undefined, and the right-hand side if it is (i.e., `const yes = mightBeTrueOrUndefined ?? true;` will be true if `mightBeTrueOrUndefined` is undefined (or null), but will be false if `mightBeTrueOrUndefined` is false.

Comment: in here i want to handle uncaught ( undefined ) 

const { has_children } = object.find(f => f.id === this.form.id)

this.form.has_children = has_children ?? true
still on undefined error with that case